# I can turn your pet into a god

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I can never see myself.
>
> I can turn your pet into a god.
>
> I can make sweets unpleasant.
>
> I will take your guns away, and you will feel secure.
>
> I can turn the sun into a bunch of rodents.

Who am I?

Comment: please take guns away from those crazy people!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Answer:

> a mirror

because

> reversing strings. Second line is DOG -> GOD, third is DESSERTS -> STRESSED (?), fourth is GUNS -> SNUG, and fifth is STAR -> RATS. The first isn't a wordplay clue; I think it's just saying that the mirror doesn't appear in itself.

Comment: I have no idea how you did it so fast :)

Comment: @Dotan To be honest I thought of mirror straight away from the first line but had no clue how to fit it to the rest of them.

Comment: About the first clue: what if you have two spoilers facing each other?

Answer (score 16):

You are

> **A mirror**.

Because

```
I can never see myself
```

> Mirrors cannot ever see themselves.

```
I can turn your pet into a god
```

> **dog** → **god**

```
I can make sweets unpleasant
```

> **desserts** → **stressed**

```
I will take you guns away, and you will feel secure
```

> **guns** → **snug** (from @ManyPinkHats)

```
I can turn the sun into a bunch of rodents
```

> **star** → **rats**

Comment: Oof, just shy of a minute later. I like your formatting better, though :)

Comment: @NicHartley Yeah, formatting cost me the checkmark and a lot of upvotes. Oh well! :)

Answer (score -1):

> Any poison that a dead pet transfers to its owner would fit as well.

---

I can never see myself

> - poison does not have eyes and the pet is dead.

I can turn your pet into a god

> - god decides whether you live or die.

I can make sweets unpleasant

> - because poison.

I will take your guns away, and you will feel secure

> - because you get really weak and can't hold a gun anymore.

I can turn the sun into a bunch of rodents

> - person dying with hallucinations.

Comment: You may feel differently - but I suspect I wouldn't feel very secure in the situation you describe...

Comment: Yeah, "because you are drugged and you can't think straight" would be  a better fit for that one. I like this one though.